# How many standard license required for monitoring a remote application via VMWare?

Tags: jprofiler

I am new to this JProfiler stuff. I am responsible to determine the best Java profiler for profiling IBM JVM 1.5 for my reputed client.

As per the connectivity of our servers, we have our application running on UNIX/LINUX machine with non GUI support. We can only use SSH (from VmWare) to connect the servers. In this scenario we will be using a Windows System in VMWare (having GUI capability) where we are planning to install the profiler (using Windows based installer) with a single license.

I would require the answers of the following questions before I can propose this tool for license procurement to my client :

1. Does it support IBM Webspehere Application Server 6 which runs on IBM JVM 1.5 ?
2. Can we extract the UNIX version of the JProfiler installation (.tar) on the UNIX/LINUX remote machine and can use the non GUI integration utilities like jpenable OR jpintegrate so that the profiled application can be connected from the VmWare Windows system as mentioned above ? In this case do we have to purchase a separate license to use these utilities in the remote machine? Please note that we will be using WAS 6 with IBM JVM 1.5.

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Does it support IBM Webspehere Application Server 6 which runs on IBM JVM 1.5 ?

Yes, that is supported by JProfiler 8.

> Can we extract the UNIX version of the JProfiler installation (.tar)
>   on the UNIX/LINUX remote machine and can use the non GUI integration
>   utilities like jpenable OR jpintegrate so that the profiled
>   application can be connected from the VmWare Windows system as
>   mentioned above ?

Yes.

> In this case do we have to purchase a separate license to use these
>   utilities in the remote machine?

You don't need a license key on the remote machine, just for the JProfiler GUI.